# setup magento commerce cloud in localhost

Tags: magento2, magento2-cloud

I'm trying to set up Magento commerce cloud in localhost, I have followed this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/before/before-setup-env-2_clone.html)

my last command was **git pull origin environment-ID**,
now I show on the local folder structure, that there is no **.env** file or not a **var** folder also,
and one of my colleagues has a facing issue on API,

**`"message": "Internal Error. Details are available in the Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-6298be27bf288"`**

so I have run command : **magento-cloud mount:download** but its gives error below,

```
Enter a number to choose a mount to download from:
  [0] app/etc
  [1] pub/static
  [2] var
  [3] pub/media
  [4] All mounts
 > 4

Target directory [.]: .

Downloading files from all remote mounts to .

Are you sure you want to continue? [Y/n] Y

Downloading files from app/etc to app/etc

Hello rushikesh-solanki (UUID: caba4943-7d8b-4ed1-98ed-2680aa1e9ba6), you successfully authenticated, but could not connect to service mg5w26ssdfxhgcjw-integration-5osdjmyuq--mymagento (reason: service doesn't exist or you do not have access to it)
  Hello rushikesh-solanki (UUID: caba49s43-7d8db-4eds1-98efd-2680aas1e9ba6), you successfully authenticated, but could not connect to service mg5w26sdfxhgcjw-integration-5ojmsdyuq--mymagento (reason: service doesn't exist or you do not have access to it)
  Connection closed by 52.65.39.201 port 22
  rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
  rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.2]

                                                                                                                                              
  [ProcessFailedException]                                                                                                                    
  The command failed with the exit code: 255                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                              
  Full command: 'rsync' '--archive' '--compress' '--human-readable' '-v' 'mg5w2sd6fxhgcjw-integration-5osdjmyuq--mymagento@ssh.ap-3.magento.cloud:app/etc/' './app etc'
```

I have run command : **magento-cloud db:dump** but its gives error below

```
[ProcessFailedException]                                                                                                                    
  The command failed with the exit code: 255                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                              
  Full command: ssh '-o' 'SendEnv TERM' '-o' 'CertificateFile /home/magento/.magento-cloud/.session/sess-cli-default/ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub  
  ' '-o' 'IdentityFile /home/magento/.magento-cloud/.session/sess-cli-default/ssh/id_ed25519' '-o' 'IdentityFile /home/magento/.ssh/id_rsa'   
  '-o' 'IdentityFile /home/magento/.ssh/id_ed25519' 'mg5w2sd6fxhgcjw-integration-5ojmydsuq--mynmagento@ssh.ap-3.magento.cloud' 'echo "$MAGENTO_CL  
  OUD_RELATIONSHIPS"
```

please help me with this or give me suggestions on what should I need to do about this.
thanks in advanced.

Comment: i have found that i need to run magento-cloud mount:download command to download var folder and for database magento-cloud db:dump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just clone the project using git, you'll find the concrete command in your Cloud project page

[image]

Note that you will need to setup your public keys in your account https://accounts.magento.cloud/user/XXXX/edit under **SSH Keys** section

After that, just run `composer install` & download **app/etc/env.php** from Cloud server, replacing services info for the ones you'll use in your local environment

This should be enough to make it work locally

Comment: if i run composer install its donwload the my current cloud project folder and files?

Comment: because im cloning the already made project not new one to install

Comment: composer install will download all software / files required in your composer.* files, that's it

Comment: ok, and for download app/etc/env.php i need to run magento-cloud mount:download command

Comment: mmm not sure how you work locally... if you are in a LAMP environment you can just download that file using a FTP client (you'll find credentials to configure the sFTP connection in your Cloud project page)

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped